# Equivalence relations and partition exercise

Tags: equivalence-relations, set-partition

I have been completely stuck on a exercise about partitions and equivalence. It goes like this

```
S = {1,2,3,4}
P = {{1},{2},{3,4}}
find an equivalencerelation ~ so that S/~ = P
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated :D
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$R={(1,1)(2,2)(3,3)(4,4)(3,4)(4,3)} $ try graphing this relation whit arrows  (a graph) and you will se de equivalence relations gives you the partition you want